# ON DELETE CASCADE does not work

Tags: mysql, cascade

I have created two tables within a MySql database:

```
create table scope (
    name_scope varchar(50) not null primary key,
    description varchar(100)
);

create table value_scope (
    id_value int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name_scope    varchar(50) not null,
    value varchar(100) not null, 
    foreign key (name_scope) references scope(name_scope) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

A scope can have multiple values.  When I delete a scope; I expect its respective values to be deleted as well, but nothing happens. I try to do it the opposite way, but the scope still exists.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your DB engine?

Comment: I'm using HeidiSQL (MySQL)

Comment: It's the client; I've asked about the DB engine - MyISAM or InnoDB, for example. BTW, what version of MySQL is used?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5 with InnoDB

Comment: It is unlikely but just in case check the value of foreign_key_checks (`SELECT @@foreign_key_checks` in the same connection which is deleting the rows).

Comment: it returns `1`, i've checked, the foreign key exists...

Comment: @raina77ow sorry I've made a mistake, my engine is MyISAM

Comment: MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys (it just ignores them when you create the table). You will need to use InnoDB.

Comment: Thank you ! It works now, I learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM does not support referential integrity.Use InnoDB instead.